# Problem on terminating decimals

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A rational number A/B, where A and B are coprime, is converted into a decimal. If both A and B are less than 100 and positive, then form how many values of B will the number A/B always be a terminating decimal?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: Find out which fractions terminate and which don't (it's a simple rule).  Then determine how many pairs have it and how many dont.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try to show that $\frac{1}{B}$ can be rewritten as a terminating decimal in base $10$ iff the only prime factors of $B$ are $2$ and $5$.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. But assuming the question talks only about positive values because (-100/-5) is both a termintating number and also less than 100. So 2^4 is the maximum power of 2 and 5^2 is the maximum here. So we have 5×3=15 factors here, which can be the possible values of B. But the answer is coming out to be 16. I just wanted an another insight if my solution is right because the question can be wrong as it specifies values less than 100 only one condition. And is ambiguous one. Thanks for the solution. Could you verify my solution and answer?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't write in the way your wrote 1/B. Could you please tell me how to write like that, I use an android device.

Comment: Just try all possible values of $2^i5^j < 100$. We get:
\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 2& 4& 8& 16& 32& 64 \\
5& 10& 20& 40& 80 \\
25& 50 \\
\end{bmatrix}